# TexLive can't find wrapfig.sty while package is installed

Tags: package-management, latex

I am currently trying to create a report with LaTex. I have installed the Ubuntu packages `texlive` and `texlive-latex-extra`.

When I try to compile my document I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `wrapfig.sty' not found.
```

When I go to my terminal and use `kpsewhich` like this it can find the package.

```
$ kpsewhich wrapfig.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
```

I have installed all packages with apt-get install. I am using sublime with LaTex Tools as Editor. Anyone has an idea why the package is not recognized by the LaTex Compiler? I have looked into the folder and all other Latex packages are also in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`.

I also tried now

```
sudo texhash
```

Doesn’t change anything unfortunately.

Comment: This may be a bit embarrassing, but for me the error was that I had written `\usepackage{wrapfigure}` and not `\usepackage{wrapfig}` (without `ure`)...

Answer (score 28):

*wrapfig* package is a part of [texlive-latex-extra](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/texlive-latex-extra). You must install it:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Then, to use [wrapfig](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures), you must first add this to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{wrapfig}
```

Comment: How did this answer receive 9 up-votes? OP already has that package installed. Including it in LaTeX will not change its availability.

Comment: Because if you google "! LaTeX Error: File `wrapfig.sty' not found.", you get to this page. Then people install the latex-extra package, and the problem is solved. Sometimes answers can be more general than the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

I run texhash a second time and rebooted and somehow it is working now. Unfortunately I am not sure what solved that issue but I guess it was texash...